# How to save JSON data in cakephp

Tags: json, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP v2.2.1 stable. I have a `UsersController` with the action `add()`. I'm trying to send the user info via ajax (from the home page to `/users/add`) and save the data. My code is something like this:

```
// /app/View/Pages/home.ctp
<?php
   $data = array('User' => array('username' => 'vegeta_super_sayajin',
    'password' => 'over9000!', 'email' => 'vegeta@supersayajin.com',
    'profile_pic' => '/home/pics/scouter.jpg', 'firstname' => 'Vegeta',
    'lastname' => 'Vegeta', 'level_id' => '9001'));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?> //convert $data into json format
    $.ajax({url: '/users/add', data: "data="+data, type: 'post'});
</script>
```

How do I receive this data in the `UsersController`, so that I can process and save it?

Currently, I'm trying:

```
// /app/Controller/UsersController.php
function add() {
    if($this->request->is('post') {
        //returns "Error: [object Object] in logfile
        $this->log($this->request->data);
    } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash(__("The user could not be saved :("));
    }
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

`$this->log($this->request->data)` returns `Error: [object Object]` in the `/app/tmp/logs/error.log` file, and this user info does not exist in any of `$this->request->params`'s indexes. All my googling so far has returned only complicated cakephp v1.3 techniques. How is this done in cakephp v2.2.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code. It will work for you.

```
<?php
$data = array(
'User' => array(
    'username' => 'vegeta_super_sayajin', 
    'password' => 'over9000!',
    'email' => 'vegeta@supersayajin.com', 
    'profile_pic' => '/home/pics/scouter.jpg',
    'firstname' => 'Vegeta', 
    'lastname' => 'Vegeta', 
    'level_id' => '9001')
    );   
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>] //convert $data into json format
$.ajax({
    url: 'checks/add', 
    data: "data="+JSON.stringify(data), 
    type: 'post'});
</script>
```

And in your controller's code:

```
// /app/Controller/UsersController.php
function add() {
if($this->request->is('post') {
    $this->log(json_encode($this->request->data, true)); //returns "Error: [object Object] in logfile
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash(__("The user could not be saved :("));
}
$this->autoRender = false;
}
```

Here is the [json_decode documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). The second parameter `true` will convert the object into an array.

Comment: Yes! `JSON.stringify()` does the trick! Thank you so much for the reply, I've been tearing my hair out trying so many different things for over 8 hours straight.